# Can i view "deployments" in the google cloud kubernetes console?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, kubectl, google-kubernetes-engine

I see "workloads" but are workloads the same as "deployments"?

I dont see any kubectl commands that can list ALL deployments just for describing a specific one.

Comment: Can you make it more clear this `"I dont see any kubectl commands that can list ALL deployments just for describing a specific one."`  However, workload is generic name. Deployment, StatefulSet, Pods, Jobs etc.. all are workload. https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/

Comment: Oh well I suppose that is want I was missing. Daemonset is also a deployment type?

Comment: `pods` are the basic building block of Kubernetes. `pods` are what actually run your container into a node. Deployment, DaemonSet, StatefulSet etc. are controller for pod. They control pod different way. For example, when you deploy a DaemonSet, it runs a replica of its pod in all nodes of the cluster. On the other hand, a Deployment's pods are scheduled whenever a nodes meet its resource requirements. It can be same node or different node. You can use `kubectl`command to get, list, path any of them. Check this kubectl cheat sheet: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you should use the command:

```
kubectl get deployments
```

By default, you will only see that ones that are in the namespace default. If your deployments are in other namespaces you have to specify it:

```
kubectl get deployments -n your_namespace
```

If you want to see all the deployments from all namespaces, use the following command:

```
kubectl get deployments --all-namespaces
```

From your question, if what you want is to see all you have (not just deployments), use the following command:

```
kubectl get all --all-namespaces
```

Comment: In gcp is there a kubectl to get all deployments for a gcp project?

Answer (score 0):

You can use following command to list deployments in kubernetes

```
kubectl get deployments
```